# C++ class template specialization with pointers

Tags: c++, class, templates, pointers

I have a tree structure of the following format:

```
template <typename DataType>
class Tree {

    DataType *accessData() { return data; } 

    Tree *child1, *child2;
    DataType *data;
};

template <typename DataType>
class Root : public Tree<DataType> {
    // root provides storage of nodes; when it goes out of scope, the
    // entire tree becomes invalid
    MemoryPool<Tree> nodeStorage;
    MemoryPool<DataType> dataStorage; 
};
```

I use a variety of instantiations of this template in my program. It works quite well.

One instantiation, however, uses a `DataType` which is just an enum (so it's the same size as a pointer!) and because speed is essential (both when the tree is built, and when it is accessed), I'd much rather have this instantiation use the enum directly instead of a pointer. An example how I'd like the code to look (not strict):

```
Tree<BigClass> *foo = ...;
foo->accessData()->doBigClassThings();
Tree<int> *bar = ...;
int x = 4 + bar->accessInt();
```

Now of course I could just keep the current templates but I don't like this extra pointer access and *especially* the need to allocate ints in the root. Any ideas on how I can specialize the template to provide this functionality, or other approaches?

I've tried to specialize the template like this (and a bazillion other ways)

```
template <> Tree<int> { ... }
```

But I just keep getting compile errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a traits class to deduce the type of object stored in `Tree`.

```
// The default traits.
template <typename DataType> struct TreeDataType
{
   using Type = DataType*;
};

template <typename DataType>
class Tree {

   // Define the data type using the traits class.
   using Data = typename TreeDataType<DataType>::Type;

   Data accessData() { return data; } 

   Tree *child1, *child2;
   Data data;
};
```

and then specialize `TreeDataType` for `MyEnum`.

```
template <> struct TreeDataType<MyEnum>
{
   using Type = MyEnum;
};
```

Comment: This looks really clean and short. The method names aren't distinctive but that's only a very small negative. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This was the best solution in my opinion. The specializations needed were trivial and I really like the cleanness. Thanks!

Comment: @bombax, I am glad I was able to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest defining multiple `data` classes with the same interface that you can use as `DataType` template parameters. Abstract the way the data is stored from the way the data is accessed.

```
template<typename T>
class value_data
{
private:
    T _value;

public:
    T& access() { return _value; }
    const T& access() const { return _value; }
};

template<typename T>
class unique_ptr_data
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> _value;

public:
    T& access() { assert(_value != nullptr); return *_value; }
    const T& access() const { assert(_value != nullptr); return *_value; }
};

enum class my_enum { /* ... */ };

class my_enum_data
{
private:
    my_enum _value;

public:
    my_enum& access() { return _value; }
    const my_enum& access() const { return _value; }
};
```

Then, in your `Tree` class, you can use them through their common interface:

```
template <typename DataType>
class Tree {

    auto& accessData() { return data.access(); } 

    Tree *child1, *child2;
    DataType data;
};
```

Comment: Very interesting use of `auto`, I'm going to read your entire answer, thanks!